# Have I understood the point of Inheriting class properties

Tags: c#, inheritance

In C#, I'm experimenting with classes and inheritance, and I want to see if I have grasped the concept correctly.

In my example, I create a base class 'Car' which consists of members 'Manufacturer' and 'Model' - i.e. common things all cars have.

I then define two derived classes from my base Car class:

- `SportsCar` which has additional members relevant to a sports car - naturally the color, and max speed.
- `FamilyWagon` which has alternate members relevant to a more sensible type of car - mpg and boot volume.

Both derived classes include a method that returns writes the values of the members of the base Car Class, and the derived class members to the console.

Finally, I create an instance object of `SportsCar` and `FamilyWagon` and set the base, and derived class specific members, before calling the method to show the values.

My code works (bonus!) but I am trying to understand whether there is actually an point in using a base class, and why not just create a `SportsCar` class and `FamilyWagon` class. My argument for going the inherited class route is that I can use the base class to cover the generic members common to all cars, and use the base class as a template on which I can base any other car types I define in the future.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SportsCar Sporty = new SportsCar();
        Sporty.SetGenericValues("Flaming Fandango", "Woosh");
        Sporty.SetCustomVals("Red", "200");

        FamilyWagon Clunker = new FamilyWagon();
        Clunker.SetGenericValues("Practical", "SnoozeFest");
        Clunker.SetCustomVals("60", "50");

        Console.WriteLine (Sporty.strDetails());
        Console.WriteLine (Clunker.strDetails());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Car
{
    protected string Manufacturer, Model;

    public void SetGenericValues(string Manufacturer, string Model)
    {
        this.Manufacturer = Manufacturer;
        this.Model = Model;
    }
}

public class SportsCar : Car
{
    protected string Colour, MaxSpeed;

    public void SetCustomVals(string Colour, string MaxSpeed)
    {
        this.Colour = Colour;
        this.MaxSpeed = MaxSpeed;
    }

    public string strDetails() { return ("Manufacturer: " + Manufacturer + Environment.NewLine + "Model: "+ Model + Environment.NewLine + "Colour: " + Colour + Environment.NewLine + "Max Speed: " + MaxSpeed); }
}

public class FamilyWagon : Car
{
    protected string MPG, BootVolume;

    public void SetCustomVals(string MPG, string BootVolume)
    {
        this.MPG = MPG;
        this.BootVolume = BootVolume;
    }

    public string strDetails() { return ("Manufacturer: " + Manufacturer + Environment.NewLine + "Model: " + Model + Environment.NewLine + "MPG: " + MPG + Environment.NewLine + "Boot Volume: " + BootVolume); }
}
```

Comment: Do Sports cars not have MPG measurements?  Are they _electric_ or something?  Futhermore, do family cars _not_ have color?  Can you see what I am getting at?

Comment: One of biggest benefits of inheritance is that you can cut down on reusing code. Without having `Car` as your base class, each of the other two classes would need to implement their own `Manufacturer` and `Model`. To avoid using the same code in both classes, they can inherit those properties from the base class, meaning you only need to write the code once instead of twice. Imagine how much code you would save if you had 10 classes inheriting from the base class.

Comment: This question is off topic on SO. Try https://programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Inheritance is not a code re-use tool.  The existence of the base class takes *more* code than just adding those two fields to both of the other classes would take.  There are *far* better tools available for avoiding repetition in code.  If you try to shoehorn your code into inheritance hierarchies that don't fit them just to try to avoid repetition you'll create way more work for yourself than you'll save.

Comment: @Servy Indeed, inheritance is not *exclusively for resusing code*. It is however, a big benefit of inheritance. One of many, and easy to explain in the example the op provided.

Comment: @sudsy1002 - Thank you, this helps a lot.

Comment: Lets say you have a dealership object.  do you want to have a collection for each type of car or just one collection of cars? If you add a new type of car do you want to just add a new child class or a new class and all of its supporting classes and a new collection in the dealership.  It saves code but it also simplifies the code and makes it infinitely more manageable.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Again, you're using it as an example in a situation where it has *added* code, making it *more* verbose, not less.  And again, I would highly suggest one not consider it a form of code reuse.  There are *much* better tools for avoiding code re-use that don't cause all of the problems that inheritance will.

Comment: @maccettura  My example code was just to try and provide some dinstinct members that made sense to me - the coding books I am working my way through seem to have abstract examples that are difficult to digest - my example derived class specific members was an attempt at humour - sports cars have MPG measurements, but they may not be first and foremost when choosing a sports car, where as speed is. The real world problem I am looking to solve has derived class members (properties) that are much more mundane, but definitely not common between the different classes.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Inheritance is *not at all* about code reuse. There are other, better ways to achieve reuse when inheritance is not called for by the model.

Comment: @TKK Yes, as I already said, I gave just one example of the benefits of inheritance. It was easy to explain using the op's example. If I wanted to write out some lengthy explanation I would have written a blog and pointed the op in that direction. An entire book could be written on inheritance and how it is similar/different to other available options. I didn't leave **my single comment** to explain everything there is to know about inheritance.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Your commment wasn't just incomplete.  Suggesting that inheritance has anything at all to do with code reuse is flat out wrong.

Comment: @TKK On that point we'd simply have to disagree then.

Answer (score -1):

As other have pointed out, using a base class allows code reusability and provides *polymorphism*. Although not the only way to achieve this, it is an important feature of inheritance: everything extending `Car` *is* a `Car` so you can have the following:

```
var allCars = new List<Car>();
allCars.Add(ferrariPortofin);
allCars.Add(bmwStationWagon);

foreach (var car in allCars) { ... }
```

But, one of the most important features of inheritance that you haven't touched is the concept of virtual and overriden methods. Consider the following:

```
public class Car
{
     //...

     public virtual string StrDetails() {
          return $"{Manufactures}, {Model}";

}

public class SportsCar: Car
{
    //...
    public override string StrDetails() {
          return $"{Manufactures}, {Model}, {Colour}, {MaxSpeed}";
}

public class FamilyWagon: Car
{
    //...
    public override string StrDetails() {
          return $"{Manufactures}, {Model}, {MPG}, {BootVolume}";
}
```

And now, you can do:

```
foreach (var car in allCars) { Console.WriteLine(car.StrDetails); }
```

And guess what will be printed out.

NOTE: you don't actually need `StrDetails`, `object.ToString()` is *virtual* so you could have overriden that method instead (remember, all classes and structs impicitly inherit from `object`).

NOTE 2: Its important to realize that *inheritance* is not the all purpose tool to acheive polymorphism and code reusability. There are other tools available which depending on the specific scenario are equally valid; interfaces, composition, etc.